# Install Ubuntu LTS on a Primergy RX300 S4

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rack

I'm a sysadmin beginner so bear with me. We got delivered a [Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S4](https://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/catalog-rx300-s4.pdf) rack server and we need to install *Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3* on it. The supported OS have not listed Ubuntu or Debian - is it still possible to install it or do we have to order a [S5/S6 version](http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/dp_DebianUbuntu-lts-en.pdf) according to Fujitsu?

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not listed in the supported OS list, then there are reasons behind it and you should think twice before installing it, even if it is possible. Because, in such a case, may be you won't get any OS support contract or patch/update for the OS.

If you understand the consequences and want to go ahead, I guess there are materials available online.

A quick google search reveals, only the following models are supported (fujitsu official site):

[Installation of Ubuntu LTS 14.04 on Fujitsu PRIMERGY Servers](ftp://ftp.ts.fujitsu.com/community-linux/ubuntu-lts/14.04/FTS_README_for_UBUNTULTS1404.html)

> Supported Servers:
>
> - RX200S8 *)
> - RX300SS8
> - RX2540M1